# How to work Google Sheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I am working in Google sheets which is the same as the excel program.

How do you make it so that when one cell is changed in a column all of the cells in that column are also changed so that they all contain the same value entered?

Comment: Just make the cell content a reference to the source cell.  If A1 is what will change, make the other cells: `=A1`  To enter the formula once and copy it, anchor it: `=$A$1`.  Are you sure you couldn't find this with a search?

Comment: There is no need to move this question to web apps

Comment: @Andria, BTW, Google Sheets is very similar to Excel, but not identical. The safe approach is to ask Google questions on Web Apps. What sometimes happens is a question is posted as Excel when the OP is actually using Sheets or LO Calc or something else. It turns out not to behave exactly the same, and everybody wastes a lot of time figuring out why nobody can replicate the other person's results. It's unfair to answerers.